# QT serial port not working

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm trying to write \ read from a serial device using a usb / rs 232 cable.
I'm pretty sure that my code writes " #002s " (this is a control code) to the serial device, because

a) the serial port is open

b) the serial port is writable

c) the code successfully navigates  "wait For Bytes Written (-1)"

d) when using a serial port sniffer the data is successfully written.

The issue I have is that I don't receive any data, and no data is being emitted from the other device. When using qt terminal writing the same "  #002s " produces the correct response.

Any ideas?

many thanks.

```
    #include "test_serial.h"
#include "ui_test_serial.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QtSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>

QSerialPort *serial;
Test_Serial::Test_Serial(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Test_Serial)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

  serial = new QSerialPort(this);
  connect(serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(serialReceived()));
  serial->setPortName("COM1");
  serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
  serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
  serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
  serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
  serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
  serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); 

  if (serial->isOpen() && serial->isWritable())
 {
  QByteArray input;

  input = "#";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  input = "0";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  input = "0";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  input = "2";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  input = "s";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  input = "\r";
  serial->write(input);
  serial->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  serial->flush();

  serial->waitForReadyRead(100);
  QByteArray output = serial->readAll();
  ui->label_2->setText(output);

}}


Test_Serial::~Test_Serial()
{
    delete ui;
    serial->close();
}

void Test_Serial::serialReceived()
{
    QByteArray output;
    output = serial->readAll();
    ui->label->setText("output");
}
```

Comment: techneaz thanks for the reply. Everything's working now turned out to be a timing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that the `readyread` flag is only emitted if theirs data to read. However I was sending the data too quickly for the external device to receive it. This meant that some data was lost thus the device never recognised it as a valid command.

This meant that it was still waiting for the message to finish, hence the "IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK) UP STATUS_CANCELLED COM1" error message upon closing the program. This also explains why their were no error messages with regards to writing data.

This also explains why the same program occasionally managed to read data, and at other times failed, (even without rebuilding the program, just re-running it.) When the data was read, the processor was more loaded, i.e. programs running in the background. This meant that the data was transmitted more slowly and thus the external device could recognise the commands and thus reply.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to write " #002s ", Why not write at once? May be the serial device cant identify the control code when you write each character.

   ```
   void Test_Serial::writeDataToSerialPort()
   {
       QByteArray input = QString("#002s").toLocal8Bit();
       serial->write(input);
   }
   ```
2. And no need for this reading part .

   ```
       serial->waitForReadyRead(100);
       QByteArray output = serial->readAll();
       ui->label_2->setText(output);
   ```

   The `Test_Serial::serialReceived` will be called any way when you have the response from the serial device.
3. And you can catch the error on opening the port by using the `error` `signal` from `QSerialPort`

   ```
   connect(serial,SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)),this,SLOT(serialPortError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));

   void Test_Serial::serialPortError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
   {
       //Print error etc.
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my codes still not working properly. Its really odd now because it's worked correctly twice, but when i've come to re-run it without changing anything its stopped working. When I've checked what "terminal" outputs theirs a line with "Mask - 0x00000001 (EV_RXCHAR)" which my program doesn't output.                            Thanks again for replying so quickly.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild? And precisely what is not working?

Comment: I did rebuild it but forgot to clean it. The issue is that the other device is meant to send back a reply when "#002s" is sent to it, but currently its not doing anything. In the serial port sniffer this command appears when I close down the program "IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK) UP STATUS_CANCELLED     COM1 
"

Comment: 1. Do you get any serial port opening error?This will ex. tell you if the port is already open by some other app. 2. Is "COM1" the right port? You can use `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()` to check for the available ports 3. Is the message reaching the serial device?  4.Providing details about the actual issue you are facing rather than making general statements will help someone here to solve your issue.

Comment: Where are you using the serial port sniffer? on the serial device end or on the system running this program? . Note: The port if opened in serial port sniffer, the QSerial Port cannot open it!!